# Immutable.listCopyfOf throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, guava

I'm using google gauva version 11.0.1 and have this piece of code:

```
ImmutableList.copyOf(items);
```

Where items is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  I occasionally see this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:126)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyFromCollection(ImmutableList.java:278)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:247)
at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:217)
```

Given the issue lies entirely within the guava library, does anyone know why?

**Update based on correct answer below**

Thanks for the help from wolfcastle, I managed to reproduce the issue in isolation, outside of my application.

```
final int itemsToPut = 30000;

final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer> items = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       for (int i = 0; i < itemsToPut; i++) {
           items.add(i);
           }
    }
}, "putter-thread").start();
final Iterable<String> transformed = Collections2.transform(items, new Function<Integer, String>() {
    public String apply(Integer integer) {
        return "foo-" + integer;
    }
});
ImmutableList.copyOf(transformed);
```

Running this produces the following everytime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 21480
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:126)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyFromCollection(ImmutableList.java:278)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:247)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:217)
```

To solve in my application, I found a number of options.

**Moving away from Collections2**

By switching from Collections2.transform to Iterables.transform, the problem goes away.

**Moving away from Java 1.5**

Whilst this wasn't possible in my situation, I tried it with Java 1.6 and Java 1.7 and the problem goes away.  I suspect this is due to a change in implementation in AbstractCollection.toArray() from 1.5:

1.5

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    Object[] result = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> e = iterator();
    for (int i=0; e.hasNext(); i++)
        result[i] = e.next();
    return result;
}
```

1.6

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
        return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}
```

**Copying the ConcurrentLinkedQueue first**

Performing a transform on a non-thread safe Collection is obviously far from ideal.  If for some reason I had to stay with Collections2.transform, I can solve the issue by taking a copy of the items collection first.

Comment: What is `items` in this case? Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The `size()` of `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is not necessarily the same for all the time the immutable list needs it (for creating the array and reading the values).

Comment: Hi Jon - I'm currently trying to produce an isolated example that reproduces this and will post if and when I can do that.  I'm also tempted to upgrade to a later version of guava, in case that helps.  I'm suspecting it may be due to trying to copy an Iterable that's being updated at the same time.

Comment: If you are really using java.util.ConcurrentLinkedQueue, it is thread-safe, so even if another thread is iterating over it, that shouldn't be a problem. The iterator and the toArray calls might see different views of the queue, but it will be safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the toArray() method of your collection. You say you are using a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, but your stack trace shows `AbstractCollection.toArray`. This seems fishy since `java.util.ConcurrentLinkedQueue` has its own toArray implementation.

What collection are you really using? I suspect that collection and not `ImmutableList`.

Comment: Great spot.  I found a call to Collections2.transform on the CLQ.  This then means that the copyOf is performed on a TransformedCollection and not the CLQ.  I'll dig a bit deeper and update the question (or answer it) once I've found more.  But TransformedCollection does indeed explain why we see the AbstractCollection.

Comment: Yes, that would explain it. `TransformedCollection` is a live view of the underlying `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. The javadoc for the transform method says "The returned collection isn't threadsafe or serializable, even if fromCollection is"

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the size of the List is changing during the execution of `copyOf()`?

If the size is checked at the beginning of the method, but the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` size is increased, it would cause a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.